# List of dates for given day of the week Swift

Tags: ios, swift3

I need to get the List of dates for the given date of the week.

As an example :
If user select the random date from picker Like 2017-6-7, 
I needs to get and display the dates of the week.
[2017-6-4, 2017-6-5, 2017-6-6, 2017-6-7, 2017-6-8, 2017-6-9, 2017-6-10]

I couldn't find any solution on the internet.

Thank you

Comment: Using `(NS)DateComponents` and iterating and changing the value of the `weekDay` should do the trick.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
let dateInWeek = Date()//7th June 2017

let calendar = Calendar.current
let dayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: dateInWeek)
let weekdays = calendar.range(of: .weekday, in: .weekOfYear, for: dateInWeek)!
let days = (weekdays.lowerBound ..< weekdays.upperBound)
    .compactMap { calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0 - dayOfWeek, to: dateInWeek) }

print(days)
```

It will give you this:

> 4 June 2017(Sunday)
>   5 June 2017
>   6 June 2017
>   7 June 2017
>   8 June 2017
>   9 June 2017
>   10 June 2017(Saturday)

---

**Start fromMonday**
The above is default behavior for my calendar that's why it is starting from Sunday.
If you want start from Monday then do this change:

```
let dayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: dateInWeek) - 1
```

It depends on which locale your calendar is in.

Comment: It works fine. If I needs to get if start from Monday and ends with Sunday what should I do?

Comment: you need to adjust `dayOfWeek` accordingly, look at my edit

Comment: When the week starts from Monday, the provided solution gets **the next week** of the target week if the `dateInWeek` is set to _Sunday_.

Comment: Slightly updated this solution with 
`calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfMonth, for: startOfDay)` 
to handle proper week when use Monday as start day

Answer (score 1):

This is a starting point using the date math skills of `Calendar`

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.firstWeekday = 1 // adjust first weekday if necessary
var startOfWeek = Date()
var interval : TimeInterval = 0.0
_ = calendar.dateInterval(of:.weekOfYear, start: &startOfWeek, interval: &interval, for: Date())
for i in 0..<7 {
    print(calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: startOfWeek)!)
}
```

Comment: Oh man, that `dateInterval(of:start:interval:for:)` is nasty, using `inout`parameters to return values. It would be much more Swifty to return a tuple. Still, your code gets the job done.

Comment: @DuncanC Well, it's originally Obj-C API so nothing we can do apart from adding a better method in an extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
 let today = Date()
  let  weekStartDate = today.getWeekStartDate(fromDate: today)
   for i in 0..<5 {
    let nextDate = weekStartDate?.getNextDay(value: i, currentDate:weekStartDate)
}

func getWeekStartDate(fromDate : Date?) -> Date? {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        if let date = fromDate {
            var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            calendar.firstWeekday = 3
            var startDate : Date = Date()
            var interval : TimeInterval = 0

            if calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &startDate, interval: &interval, for: date) {
                print("Start of week is \(startDate)")
                // prints "Start of week is 2017-01-01 06:00:00 +0000"
                return startDate
            }
        }
        return nil
    }


     func getNextDay(value : Int, currentDate : Date?) -> Date? {

            let dayComponenet = NSDateComponents()
            dayComponenet.day = value

            let theCalendar = NSCalendar.current
            let nextDate = theCalendar.date(byAdding: dayComponenet as DateComponents, to: currentDate!)
            return nextDate

        }
```

Hope this will help!.